# Change/Show trim path on svg?

Tags: animation, svg, android-animation, trim

I am new to animation in android (and in general) and I'm using a library *RichPath*, the thing is that I want the **borderlines** of the SVG to animate, and then filled with color.
Its animating well, but I think my SVG needs something else because its only doing the outside border, and then filling in, I did it in inkscape based on a text:

[image: like this]

Desired:

[image]

I'm asuming it is something about the trim path because of the code for animating:

```
RichPathAnimator.animate(svg)
            .trimPathEnd(0, 1)
            .duration(800)
            .animationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    a1.setFillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStop() {
                }
            })
```

My vector asset:

```
<path
    android:name="a1"
    android:pathData="m10.511,2.596q0.869,0 1.569,0.418 0.711,0.406 1.118,1.129 0.418,0.711 0.418,1.592v2.517q0,0.248 -0.169,0.418 -0.158,0.158 -0.406,0.158 -0.248,0 -0.418,-0.158 -0.158,-0.169 -0.158,-0.418v-0.418q-0.395,0.485 -0.96,0.756 -0.564,0.271 -1.219,0.271 -0.813,0 -1.479,-0.406 -0.655,-0.406 -1.039,-1.118 -0.373,-0.722 -0.373,-1.603 0,-0.881 0.406,-1.592 0.406,-0.722 1.118,-1.129 0.722,-0.418 1.592,-0.418zM10.511,7.846q0.564,0 1.016,-0.271 0.463,-0.282 0.722,-0.756 0.26,-0.485 0.26,-1.084 0,-0.598 -0.26,-1.084 -0.26,-0.485 -0.722,-0.756 -0.452,-0.282 -1.016,-0.282 -0.564,0 -1.027,0.282 -0.452,0.271 -0.722,0.756 -0.26,0.485 -0.26,1.084 0,0.598 0.26,1.084 0.271,0.474 0.722,0.756 0.463,0.271 1.027,0.271z"
    android:fillColor="#3768d2"
    android:strokeColor="#3768d2"
    android:strokeWidth="0.26458332" />
```

Thanks in advance (y)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The more work people have to do to reproduce the problem, the less likely you are to get assistance.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I uploaded the repo, you could the see problem at login screen (the only one) in the initial commit in [this_github](https://github.com/JonathanJumper/balance), cheers

Comment: What program did you use to create the original SVG?  Was it Sketch by any chance?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau It was Inkscape based on a text

Comment: I know the VectorDrawable renderer in Android does (or did) have bugs rendering relative (ie. lower case) path commands. Perhaps it is this that is causing your problem. Try saving your SVG from Inkscape with absolute path commands. To do this do: Edit->Preferences->Input/Output->SVG output->Path string format->Absolute. Then resave and reconvert to VectorDrawable.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau did not work :l

Comment: Does the VectorDrawable render correctly when it is just placed in an ImageView?  I.e. no animation?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau It does. Nevermind I'll try lottie

Comment: Have you considered that it could be a bug in the third party library you are using? Have you tried just making an AnimatedVectorDrawable instead?

Comment: @Jumper Note in xml use android:fillColor to fill your path with the color or remove it if you don't.
or/and use android:strokeColor to show the border and set a color to it.

Comment: @Jumper also I see that the way which the tool has draw the path isn't suitable for your animation, it consists of outer line and inner line, try to draw it with one line.
OR
if you want to animate the two lines at the same time you should split it into two paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have split your vector into 3 paths and it works with me:

Java:

```
RichPath outPath = richPathView.findRichPathByName("outPath");
RichPath innerPath = richPathView.findRichPathByName("innerPath");
RichPath filledPath = richPathView.findRichPathByName("filledPath");
filledPath.setFillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

RichPathAnimator
            .animate(outPath, innerPath)
            .trimPathStart(1, 0)
            .duration(800)
            .thenAnimate(filledPath)
            .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, 0xff3768d2)
            .duration(800)
            .start();
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">

    <path
        android:name="outPath"
        android:pathData="M12,1.7c1.9,0,3.6,0.5,5.2,1.4c1.6,0.9,2.8,2.1,3.7,3.7c0.9,1.6,1.4,3.3,1.4,5.3v8.3c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4
    c-0.3,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.3,0.5s-1-0.2-1.4-0.5c-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.8-0.5-1.4V19c-0.9,1.1-1.9,1.9-3.2,2.5c-1.2,0.6-2.6,0.9-4,0.9
    c-1.8,0-3.4-0.4-4.9-1.3c-1.4-0.9-2.6-2.1-3.4-3.7C2.1,15.7,1.7,14,1.7,12s0.4-3.7,1.3-5.3C4,5.2,5.2,3.9,6.8,3
    C8.3,2.1,10.1,1.7,12,1.7L12,1.7z"
        android:strokeColor="#3768d2"
        android:strokeWidth="0.5"/>


    <path
        android:name="innerPath"
        android:pathData="M12,19c1.2,0,2.4-0.3,3.4-0.9c1-0.6,1.8-1.5,2.4-2.5c0.6-1.1,0.9-2.3,0.9-3.6c0-1.3-0.3-2.5-0.9-3.6
    c-0.6-1.1-1.4-1.9-2.4-2.5C14.4,5.3,13.3,5,12,5S9.6,5.3,8.6,5.9c-1,0.6-1.8,1.4-2.4,2.5C5.7,9.5,5.4,10.7,5.4,12
    c0,1.3,0.3,2.5,0.9,3.6c0.6,1,1.4,1.9,2.4,2.5C9.6,18.7,10.8,19,12,19z"
        android:strokeColor="#3768d2"
        android:strokeWidth="0.5"/>


    <path
        android:name="filledPath"
        android:fillColor="#3768d2"
        android:pathData="M12,1.7c1.9,0,3.6,0.5,5.2,1.4c1.6,0.9,2.8,2.1,3.7,3.7c0.9,1.6,1.4,3.3,1.4,5.3v8.3c0,0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4
    c-0.3,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.3,0.5s-1-0.2-1.4-0.5c-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.8-0.5-1.4V19c-0.9,1.1-1.9,1.9-3.2,2.5c-1.2,0.6-2.6,0.9-4,0.9
    c-1.8,0-3.4-0.4-4.9-1.3c-1.4-0.9-2.6-2.1-3.4-3.7C2.1,15.7,1.7,14,1.7,12s0.4-3.7,1.3-5.3C4,5.2,5.2,3.9,6.8,3
    C8.3,2.1,10.1,1.7,12,1.7L12,1.7z M12,19c1.2,0,2.4-0.3,3.4-0.9c1-0.6,1.8-1.5,2.4-2.5c0.6-1.1,0.9-2.3,0.9-3.6
    c0-1.3-0.3-2.5-0.9-3.6c-0.6-1.1-1.4-1.9-2.4-2.5C14.4,5.3,13.3,5,12,5S9.6,5.3,8.6,5.9c-1,0.6-1.8,1.4-2.4,2.5
    C5.7,9.5,5.4,10.7,5.4,12c0,1.3,0.3,2.5,0.9,3.6c0.6,1,1.4,1.9,2.4,2.5C9.6,18.7,10.8,19,12,19z"/>

</vector>
```

Comment: Did you use any tool to split the SVG into 3 paths? This feels like a lot of work if done manually! Can you throw some pointers please.

Comment: Actually, you can use a vector design tool like Adobe Illustrator to do that job but if you have no experience in design tools like me you can split paths manually but you need to understand the path data.
for example, the next path data draws a line from point(0,0) to point(100,0)

pathData="M0 0 L100 0"


for more details about path data commands check https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp